# Why does my cloth shirt sim inflate

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, pose-mode

I have this shirt:
[image: before hitting play]

which should just fall onto my character when I hit play. But instead it inflates like this:
[image: after hitting play]

I have all collisions and self collisions set to the minimum but it doesnt seem to matter. I noticed the sim works properly when I massively scale everything up, but the character and the shirt  should be big enough for the sim to work.
I have another character with a shirt in this same scene that doesn't behave like this and I can't figure out why.

You can find the blend file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I4rpa-lCSrVwc46zBq_EoLJU6_jiWjOA/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please next time share just a minimum of a scene needed to replicate an issue. So we can faster locate the issue and doesn't spend time by study your file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body object (when Scaled back to 1 (=1.75 m)) has still set *Collision* > **Outer Thickness** 0.1 which means 10 cm ... when set 0.01 (1 cm) just for testing purpose, the t-shirt is not "inflated".

[image]

Comment: Thanks vklidu! That fixed it!